# Blackberry application storage - How and Where?

Tags: blackberry, storage

I need to figure out how to store the data for my application.

Its a language app so it will store thousands of different words in different languages.

The data will be read only but I may need to update the data if I add new words at a later date.

So whats the best way -- in a file or a database -- and where should it be stored? Within the application or sent down to the SD Card.

Any advice in the simplest terms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What average amount of data in KB do you expect to store?